# Is gen_server restart strategy copy state?

Tags: erlang, elixir, beam

Erlang world not use try-catch as usual. I'm want to know how about performance when restart a process vs try-catch in mainstream language.

A Erlang process has it's small stack and heap concept which actually allocate in OS heap. Why it's effective to restart it?

Hope someone give me a deep in sight about Beam what to do when invoke a restart operation on a process.

Besides, how about use `gen_server` which maintain state in  it's process. Will cause a copy state operate when `gen_server` restart?

Thanks

Comment: If a gen_server crashes and it's supervisor starts a new one, it will not copy the state. The whole point is to be put back into a "known good" state. If it copied the state, the data could have gotten into a corrupted/bad state and that is the reason it crashed in the first place. It is possible to copy the state to the new gen_server manually, but you need to be very careful with something like that.

Comment: hi, @JustinWood, I have two question. 1. "known good" state is init function defined one? 2. go to new initial state will create the process just like first time create the process?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend having a read of https://ferd.ca/the-zen-of-erlang.html

Here's my understanding: restart is effective for fixing "Heisenbug" which only happens when the (Erlang) process is in some weird state and/or trying to handle a "weird"  message.

The presumption is that you **revert to a known good state** (by restarting), which should handle all normal messages correctly. Restart is not meant to "fix all the problems", and certainly not for things like bad configuration or missing internet connection. By this definition we can see it's very dangerous to copy the state when crash happened and try to recover from that, because this is defeating the whole point of going back to a known state.

The second point is, say this process only crashes when handling an action that only 0.001% (or whatever percentage is considered negligible) of all your users actually use, and it's not really important (e.g. a minor UI detail) then it's totally fine to just let it crash and restart, and **don't need to fix it**. I think it can be a productivity enabler for these cases.

---

Regarding your questions in the OP comment: yes just whatever your `init` callback returns, you can either build the entire starting state there or source from other places, totally depend on the use case.

Comment: Hi, almost understand the state and give a let it crash more deep insight, thanks. Just has some wonder as the refers, **only 0.001% of all your users actually use**, should I design a db library hold disconnect with let it crash or use try-catch handle exception and return nil to caller?

Comment: @LoranceChen using "let it crash" doesn't limit what kind of interface you can give  to the user as a library designer. E.g. you can still choose to wrap it in an `{:error, :timeout}` tuple or raise a timeout exception. In fact, the Elixir community usually follows this idiom where a library would provide both a `call` and `call!` version of a same function, only the former returns a tuple (never crash the caller) and the latter raises, so end users can choose what kind of behaviour they want.

The original comment was focusing on application design's point of view, but it's the same idea.